# Query in an array of objects using findOne not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using this in mongoose:

```
const motherLevel = await db.Mother.findOne({});

const b = motherLevel.cards[level];

console.log(b);
```

I get this array:

```
[ { cards: [ [Object] ], _id: 60ef57c59f44361488e5cf96, unit: 1 } ]
```

Then I want to get the object inside based on unit: 1 so I use this one:

```
const c = motherLevel.cards[level].findOne({ unit: 1 });
```

But it doesn't return any result!!!

How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**

I have this structure in my collection (Note that I have only this single collection and I want to push some data into the cards nested deeply inside)

[image]

As you see I want to go to each of the levels first for instance into the starter level in our case...

Then I want to pick the unit 1 and push a new card into the cards which is a  part of the unit one object right?

So far I can get the level which is the array containing different units but I cannot pick that unit to push my card into it...

Comment: What does console.log(c) say?

Comment: it returns nothing........

Comment: It would either say undefined or an empty array or null or maybe throw an error. I don't think it will return nothing right?

Comment: I think maybe just an empty line ...

Answer (score 1):

You are using findOne on a javascript array but findOne is a method of mongoose/mongodb at following line

```
const c = motherLevel.cards[level].findOne({ unit: 1 });
```

if you want find that unit 1 is exists in the motherLevel.cards array you should use following, this will return the first match of card that have unit 1

```
const c = motherLevel.cards.find(card=>c.unit===1)
```

or if you want to all cards that have unit 1 you can use filter like following, this will return all the cards that have unit 1

```
const c = motherLevel.cards.find(card=>c.unit===1)
```